# Google Chrome should not display flash above div or iframe

Tags: flash, google-chrome, iframe, html, overlay

I have a div that I want to be able to display over an iframed youtube flash player (and I do not want to embed the object directly) or iframed flash advertising. So far, my solution is to display an transparent iframe behind the div, which works for Firefox, Safari, and IE8, however, Google Chrome doesn't appear to follow suit. Because the flash objects are iframed from a third party site, I can't modify their wmode, either.

Any ideas on how to get this div to display over third-party flash in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Youtube offers to set the wmode through the url. Adding `?wmode=opaque` to the iframe source should fix the problem.

Example:

```
<iframe width="455" height="371" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/x?wmode=opaque" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```